# Is a keyframed transition possible in Core Animation?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

I know that keyframed transitions are possible in Core Animation via setting the `path` property on the `CAAnimation` instance. However, `CATransition` does not seem to have this functionality. Does anyone know any other ways to control the transition apart from setting the timing function?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you're trying to accomplish here?  Since CATransitions don't actually move the CALayer (just animate its contents changing), something like a path property doesn't really make sense for them.

Comment: I need to be able to tell the transition that I want it to be, for example, 50% done after 5 seconds and take 10 seconds to do the other half of the transition

Comment: What you've described is a custom timing function.

Comment: True, but thing is that the custom timing function isn't flexible enough. Not all the timing options I would like to have can be described by a 2-point Bezier curve. Anyway, I think the answer _is_ no and I will have to try to tweak the custom function. Many thanks for your help Kevin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be no. If you want to do this sort of thing, you have to add the CAAnimation yourself rather than depending on transitions. The transitions probably depend on some deep workings of CoreAnimation, because they don't work the same way normal animations do (they don't move the object in question, they control how the new content of the object replaces the old).